# A solution for two-binding between angular and a style sheet

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, gruntjs

I know this sounds silly but I'm writing a wysiwyg editor that allows Designers to create style guides.  I've become very fascinated with 2 way binding in angular and was curious if it was possible to two-way bind between a css sheet and a `ng-model` input field.  Currently, I'm making a dynamic style guide that allows a designer to colorpick a primary, secondary colors of a page.  These color will change the entire theme of the site uniformly and it would be awesome to do this from the stylesheet itself.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="color.primary" />
<button class="btn primary-color" />
```

**CSS**

```
.primary-color {
  background: {{color.primary}};
}
```

**js**
    $scope.color {primary: '00f', secondary: '#e58'}

I know there are plenty of directives like `ng-style` and `ng-class` But I fear that every  tag will have to be a directive because everything could have an ng-style/ng-class tag.  Thus making my code not very dry and hard to maintain.

What if I wanted a dynamic style guide of css.  A sheet that I could store as key value pairs of CSS into server like firebase, perhaps even 3way bind the changing of colors in real time?  I'm pretty sure this cannot be accomplished using solely angular... would anyone have any ideas on pre compilers or hacks to accomplish this task so that it would result in one clean style guy?

Comment: Just spit balling, but perhaps you could have a service that handles changing the styles.  I tried doing some searching and it seems the CSS files aren't really accessible directly from Javascript, my guess is using jQuery selectors to get the elements based on class and updating their styles is the best bet.  You could implement this  in service and inject it into a directive that you could then use in the inputs that you want to use the model from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was pretty fun to work on.

You have access to all of the styles on a page through `document.styleSheets`, so you just need scope the rules on a style. So lets say that I have this class:

```
.class {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: blue;
}
```

How jsfiddle implements sheets, this is the third style sheet added to the document, so I can just assign to the scope like this:

```
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.styles = document.styleSheets[3].rules;     
}]);
```

This would let you do things like `$scope.styles[0].style['color'] = 'red'` to change the color of anything with class to red. Since it's the first thing in the style array.

But that's not cool enough, so we want to create a directive where we can change these from a ui. So we'd like to know all of the things that class controls, to create controls for them, So we can manipulate the css string to get all of those.

Next we have to create a temporary scoped object on the directive that starts off with all of the styles. The reason is that style sheets have checking, so as you type into an input if you do something like `$scope.styles[0].style['color'] = 'g'` and it was red, it will just reset to red.

So we create an input for each style type, with ng-model of our temp, then just listen for changes and attempt to assign to the style sheet.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jk28j/1/) where I implement it, but the directive looks like this.

```
myApp.directive('styler', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            styles: '='
        },
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div ng-repeat="type in types">{{type}} <input ng-change="Change(type)" ng-model="temp_styles[type]"/></div>',
        link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {      
            // get the actual styles
            var types = scope.styles.cssText.replace(/ /g, '').split('{')[1].split('}')[0].split(';');
            scope.types = [];
            scope.temp_styles = {};
            // get rid of "" element at the end
            types.pop();
            for (var i in types) {
                var split = types[i].split(':');
                scope.types.push(split[0]);
                scope.temp_styles[split[0]] = split[1];
            }
            scope.Change = function(type) {
                scope.styles.style[type] = scope.temp_styles[type];
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Cool, dynamic two way binding of styles!

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hassassin... bravo my man.. this is great.  I've marked it correct but would you have any insight on how to use REGEX or some way to target the isolated scope of styles:'=' using the string of the class and not it's array position?  I've made a jsfiddle excersize that could be interesting for you ... http://jsfiddle.net/Jk28j/4/  I can make a new question if you want more points lol

Comment: In general I think it would be better for it to be another question, but since it's not a good answer it's fine. You can either add the class to styler in html and remove it in the link function, or you can pass it as '@' to styler and loop through all of the style sheets and test the selector text.

Comment: Your `document.styleSheets[3].rules` should probably be `document.styleSheets[3].cssRules` instead.

Comment: Good call, cssRules appears to be the W3C standard.